# DefaultTextFormat vs SetTextFormat

Tags: actionscript-3

here are 2 code blocks.

```
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

addChild(myTextField);

myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
myTextFormat.size = 15;
myTextFormat.color = 0x0000FF;

myTextField.text = "some text";
**myTextField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);**
```

VS

```
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

addChild(myTextField);

myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
myTextFormat.size = 15;
myTextFormat.color = 0x0000FF;

**myTextField.defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat;**
```

So , What's the difference between 
setTextFormat() and defaultTextFormat ? Why two different ways ( one by property another by method) to do things.

Tested with some more code :

```
var my_txt:TextField =new TextField();
    my_txt.type = TextFieldType.INPUT
     var my_fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
     my_fmt.color = 0xFF0000;

     my_txt.text = "this is for setTextFormat with range";
     my_txt.setTextFormat(my_fmt,0,3);

    // my_txt.text = "this is for setTextFormat without range";
    // my_txt.setTextFormat(my_fmt);

    // my_txt.defaultTextFormat = my_fmt;
    // my_txt.text = "this is for default text format";

    addChild(my_txt);
```

V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setTextFormat allows you to change the formatting on parts of the text. Check out the other two parameters of setTextFormat. When you set defaultTextFormat it is applied to all the text that you add to the TextField.

More info :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#defaultTextFormat

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat

Edit : 
Also setTextFormat doesn't work on text that is inserted after you set the format. Adobe says 
"Any text inserted manually by the user, or replaced by the replaceSelectedText() method, receives the default text field formatting for new text, and not the formatting specified for the text insertion point. To set the default formatting for new text, use defaultTextFormat."

Comment: ok,thnx. But many a times, when trying to use a dynamic font, things don't work unless defaultTextFormat is used. So there must be something more about it's significance.

Comment: Doesn't work means the format doesn't change? setTextFormat doesn't work if stylesheets are applied to the text. From adobe:
Note: This method does not work if a style sheet is applied to the text field.

Comment: See edit, so setTextFormat only sets the format of the text currently in the textField it doesn't affect text that the user inputs.

Comment: Actually `setTextFormat` only apply the format within a range. If you do not specify a range when calling this method, it will apply to all the text.

Comment: so does that mean, if i don't specify a range then "setTextFormat" would apply to all the text ( Similar to how defaultTextFormat works ?)
btw, I have edited my question adding the last block of code, i just experimented with.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani yes, if you don't specify a range in `setTextformat` it will behave like `defaultTextFormat`, but unlike `defaultTextFormat` `setTextFormat` will not apply the formatting to newly inserted text, i.e  text entered by a user or text inserted with the `replaceSelectedText` method.