# DefaulTextFormat in INPUT TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Here's my Code

```
var format:TextFormat=new TextFormat(); 
var text:TextField=new TextField();
text.border=true;
text.width=400;
text.multiline=true;
text.wordWrap=true;

text.type=TextFieldType.INPUT;
text.background=true;

text.text="Some text"; // Bold doesn't works with this line

format.bold=true;
text.defaultTextFormat=format;
```

I can't format text in INPUT textfield when it isn't EMPTY.How i can solve this problem or what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `defaultTextFormat`. As reference says it

> specifies the format applied to newly inserted text, such as text
>   entered by a user or text inserted with the replaceSelectedText()
>   method.

Try to use a `text.setTextFormat(format);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call setTextFormat, you may see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657570/defaulttextformat-vs-settextformat)

```
text.defaultTextFormat=format;
text.setTextFormat(format);
```

Answer (score 0):

First set `defaultTextFormat`, then set `text`.

```
format.bold=true;
text.defaultTextFormat=format;
text.text="Some text"; // Should now be bold
```