# Change text formatting of the TextField in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, text, format, textfield

I was wondering how to change text format to Arial or Futura in this code?

On the stage there is a dynamic text box named my_text but trying to change text from properties panel does not work.

Here is my code:

```
//SCROLLING SPEED
var scrolling_speed:int = 10;
//TEXT TO SCROLL
var text_to_scroll:String = "This is my text";


//establish the field
var my_text:TextField = new TextField();
//add the field to stage
addChild(my_text);
//set the text
my_text.text = text_to_scroll;
//set the x coord off right side of stage
my_text.x = stage.stageWidth;
//set y coord in middle of stage (about)
my_text.y = (stage.stageHeight/2)-(my_text.height/2);
//not selectable
my_text.selectable = false;
//no border
my_text.border = false;
//field scales with more text
my_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

//set a format
var my_text_format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
//set the color to the hex
my_text_format.color = 0x000000;
//set the font size
my_text_format.size = 24;
//apply formatting
my_text.setTextFormat(my_text_format);

//add the listener to scroll
my_text.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,move_text);

//scroll function
function move_text(myevent:Event):void {
    my_text.x-=scrolling_speed;
    if(my_text.x<(0-my_text.width)){
        my_text.x=stage.stageWidth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about changing the font face, try using the following command:

```
my_text_format.font = "Arial";
```

or

```
my_text_format.font = "Futura";
```

Consider also using `defaultTextFormat` property of the `TextField`:

```
//apply formatting
my_text.defaultTextFormat = my_text_format;
```

When you are using the `setTextFormat()` method, you are only applying the changes to the text, which is already in the form.

Here is the full code for you (Arial example is taken):

```
//SCROLLING SPEED
var scrolling_speed:int = 10;
//TEXT TO SCROLL
var text_to_scroll:String = "This is my text";


//establish the field
var my_text:TextField = new TextField();
//add the field to stage
addChild(my_text);
//set the text
my_text.text = text_to_scroll;
//set the x coord off right side of stage
my_text.x = stage.stageWidth;
//set y coord in middle of stage (about)
my_text.y = (stage.stageHeight/2)-(my_text.height/2);
//not selectable
my_text.selectable = false;
//no border
my_text.border = false;
//field scales with more text
my_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

//set a format
var my_text_format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
//set the color to the hex
my_text_format.color = 0x000000;
//set the font size
my_text_format.size = 24;
//set the font face
my_text_format.font = "Arial";
//apply formatting
my_text.defaultTextFormat = my_text_format;
my_text.setTextFormat(my_text_format);

//add the listener to scroll
my_text.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,move_text);

//scroll function
function move_text(myevent:Event):void {
    my_text.x-=scrolling_speed;
    if(my_text.x<(0-my_text.width)){
        my_text.x=stage.stageWidth;
    }
}
```

More on setting fonts in ActionScript 3.0: [ActionScript TextFormat.font values - Erik’s Brain](http://blog.erikphansen.com/actionscript-textformatfont-values/)

More on `defaultTextFormat` and `setTextFormat()`: [DefaultTextFormat vs SetTextFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657570/defaulttextformat-vs-settextformat)

Comment: Thanks exactly what i need. Would you know maybe a xml function to this so i could fetch text data from xml file or txt file?

Comment: @user3391599, unfortunately, I can not get the question yet. Do you mean getting some text formatting data from an external XML file in order to use it later for formatting AS3 TextField?

Comment: @user3391599, this link might help you: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/

I can explain it in a more detailed fashion, but I need some answer space for that rather than comments.